# Google play integrity api issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-play-integrity-api

I am migrating my app from Google play safety net API to Integrity API, but after releasing it to playstore the app is not working. It only shows loading.

My project running with Flutter framework. The play console settings and setups are done. But I don't have any idea about integrating and setup play integrity API in Flutter. Does anyone have any idea about this one?

```
implementation "com.google.android.play:integrity:1.0.1"
```

I've already added to dependencies of `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Hi, how did you resolve this?

Comment: Are you using Firebase with your app?

Answer (score 0):

In your app use the new updated BoM 31.4.0 library.

File to edit is  app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.4.0')
}
```